# Posting file by ajax "error 405 Method not Allowed" in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, ajaxform

Route

```
Route::get('/mediafile', 'MediaController@index');
```

MediaController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('UserFile');
    if($request->hasFile('UserFile')) {
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();  
        Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save(public_path('media/' . $filename));
        $media = new Media();
        $media->Description = $request->Description ? $request->Description : '';
        $media->MediaPath = $filename;
        $media->MediaName = $filename;
        $media->save();
    }

    return response()->json($media);
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-group image">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
   <label>Gambar</label><input type="file" name="UserFile" id="userfile" style="display: inline">
    <label style="margin-left: 25px">atau</label>
      <a href="http://192.168.1.12/melody4/media/select.html" class="pilihmedia btn btn-default">Pilih dari media</a>
      <input type="hidden" id="MediaID" name="CategoryMediaID" value="" />
      <br /><br />
      <span class="uploadstatus"></span>
      <div class="success infomedia infomedia alert alert-success" style="display: none">
  </div>
</div>
```

Ajax

```
$('#userfile').change(function(){
$(this).attr('disable',true);
$('.uploadstatus').html('Sedang mengupload file <img src="{{ asset('vendor/img/loading.gif') }}" alt="ajaxloading" />');
$(this).parent().ajaxSubmit({
    url: "<?php echo url('/mediafile') ?>",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    success : function(data){
      $(this).attr('disable',false);
      $('.uploadstatus').empty();
    },
    error : function(data){

    }
  });  

});
```

I got an error "405 Method Not Allowed" with using AJAX when I posted an image, I have researched and followed all the answers in the Stack Overflow, but I still can't resolve it.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Can you please post the code not images? And could you also provide the route definitions?

Comment: Note that images of textual information are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines, and thus are not a helpful format for people who would want to help you. Please replace them with formatted text. There is a button to help you format text in the editor.

Comment: @halfer oh i'm sorry.. because this is the first time for me to use stackoverflow and thankyou for the advice

Comment: You're welcome. Bear in mind that this advice is good for any help forum on the internet, and is not specific to Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+format+code+on+stack+overflow) is available on the web. It's worth using the preview window as well, to avoid a bad edit being published.

Comment: @ka_lin hello, I have already changed them into code.. sorry, because this is the first time for me to use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be issue in csrf token 
Add this line in html

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

and in ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
     });
```

and need to post image in ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Change `Route::get` to `Route::post` to handle POST requests.

If you need to support both GET and POST: use either `Route::match` or `Route::any`.

Read more about Laravel router here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing